# Set iframe location as the location in the $_GET element

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, iframe

How can I set an iframe src as the location in the $_GET properly.

Currently i'm trying this:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^stream/(.*)$ index.php?p=stream&link=$1
```

**stream.php/http://bbc.co.uk**

```
<?php
echo '    
<div class="container" style="height:1000px;">
<iframe src="'.$_GET['link'].'" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>
 ';

?>
```

This sets the iframe to go to 127.0.0.1/stream/http://bbc.co.uk when it should just go to bbc.co.uk

Comment: Sounds like a wonderful way to trick people into thinking my site is part of your site...

Comment: What, even though your site would be clearly visible in the URL?

Comment: Is that the only rewrite rule? I don't see anything that would turn `stream.php` into `stream`.

Comment: No it isn't, i've cut most of it out as it is large sorry, i can echo $_GET['link'] and access stream.php by going to /stream

Comment: for some reason when I echo $_GET['link'] it returns http:/bbc.co.uk instead of http://bbc.co.uk  (one forward slash after http: instead of two)

Comment: Yes, very clearly visible:
`stream.php/http://3468664375@3468664375/o%62s%63ur%65%2e%68t%6D`

Comment: I see little advantage of "tricking people into thinking" a site is apart of my site, especially with an iframe. This is not what i'm trying to acheive. Thanks for your input however. I do understand your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I indicated in my comment, you need to rewrite php files to remove the `.php` so that the rule you posted matches, e.g.:

```
RewriteRule (\w+).php $1
RewriteRule ^stream/(.*)$ index.php?p=stream&link=$1
```

Which means your link will be re-written as so:

```
http://example.com/stream.php/http://bbc.co.uk
http://example.com/stream/http://bbc.co.uk
http://example.com/index.php?p=stream&link=http://bbc.co.uk
```

Then your php will output:

```
<div class="container" style="height:1000px;">
<iframe src="http://bbc.co.uk" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Which works as expected.

Comment: This has the same problem, it only shows one forward slash after http: instead of two.

Comment: @user1626410 `it only shows one forward slash after http: instead of two` Where? Every stage of the rewrite has 2 and 2 show in the source code.

Comment: In the iframe src it shows <iframe src="http:/bbc.co.uk" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>

Comment: @user1626410 I cannot reproduce your problem. Run the code exactly as I've put it and remove any RewriteRules you have that aren't in my post.

Answer (score 0):

The url itself is not correct ie. it should have been in the form

```
stream.php?link=http://bbc.co.uk
```

Then you will get it in:

```
 $_GET['link']
```

Other way would be store a mapping of the above get variable with the corresponding url:

ie.

```
var urlsMapping = {"bbc":"http://bbc.co.uk","toi":"http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com"}
```

Then make your url like:

stream.php?link=bbc

**Set iframe src as**

```
urlsMapping[<?=$_GET['link']?>]
```

Comment: The point is to have a url stream.php/otherurl rewritten to index.php?p=stream&link=otherurl

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this

```
RewriteRule ^stream/(.+)$ index.php?p=stream&link=$1  [L,QSA]
```

I hope this will hep you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using preg_replace

Probably not the best option, however it did work.

```
<?php
$link = preg_replace('~http:/~si', '', $_GET['link']);
echo '    
<div class="container" style="height:1000px;">
<iframe src="http://'.$link.'" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>
 ';
?>
```